# Why cant I split the modulus?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Consider $47^{27}$ congruent to $R \pmod {55}$.

Since $ 55 = 11\times5$ which are coprime, we can say:

$R$ is congruent to $14^{27} \pmod 5 $ and$\pmod {11}$

However $14$ is $-1 \pmod 5$ so $14^{27}$ is congruent to $-1 \pmod 5$.

I checked on wolfram and the solution is $53$, which is not $-1 \pmod 5$. What gives?

Comment: Should 47 be 14, or vice versa?

Comment: Multi-character exponents should appear in braces:  "\$14^{27}\$" = $14^{27}$.  Moduli are easily handled as "\$R \pmod{55}\$" = $R \pmod{55}$.

Comment: Yeah, your mathematics is completely unreadable. Please edit so we can even know what the problem was.

Comment: edit please ...

Comment: Where does the $14$ come from?  It seems to be unrelated to $47$ in this context.

Comment: While $\,47\equiv 14\pmod{11},\,$ it is not true that $\ 47\equiv 14\pmod{5}.\ $

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
    47^{27}  
        &\cong 2^{27} \pmod{5} \\
        &\cong 2 \cdot 2^{26} \pmod{5} \\
        &\cong 2 \cdot (-1)^{13} \pmod{5} \\
        &\cong 3 \pmod{5} \text{.} \\
    53  &\cong 3 \pmod{5} \text{.} \\
    47^{27} 
        &\cong 3^{27} \pmod{11} \\
        &\cong 3 \cdot 3^{26} \pmod{11} \\
        &\cong 3 \cdot 9^{13} \pmod{11} \\
        &\cong 5 \cdot 4^{6} \pmod{11} &&(3 \cdot 9 \cong 27 \cong 5, 9^2 \cong (-2)^2 \cong 4.) \\
        &\cong 5 \cdot 5^{3} \pmod{11} \\
        &\cong 5 \cdot 125 \pmod{11} \\
        &\cong 5 \cdot 4 \pmod{11} \\
        &\cong 9 \pmod{11}  \text{.} \\
    53 &\cong 9 \pmod{11} \text{.}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

As $47\equiv-8\pmod{55}$

$47^{27}\equiv(-2^3)^{27}\pmod{55}$

$(-2^3)^{27}=-2^{81}$

Now using [Carmichael Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html),  $\lambda(55)=\cdots=20$

As $81\equiv1\pmod{20},$  $$2^{81}\equiv2^1\pmod{55}$$